# Angular Mattabgroup : How to automatically copy the form content from one tab to another tab

Tags: angular, angular-material

I’m trying to automatically copy contents of a form from one tab to another when a user enters it on UI. Ideas on how i can achieve this are appreciated.

Here’s a snippet of HTML form the other form on the next tab has same structure

```
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option" formControlName="namePreference"
<mat-radio-button class="radio-box" value="firstName”> Firstname≤/mat-radio-button›
‹mat-radio-button class="radio-box" value="lastName" >last name≤/mat-radio-button>

</mat-radio-group>
```

Comment: The value of your mat-radio-group should be accessible from the form control 'namePreference'